# determine containing pull request from (feature) branch

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to determine the **pull request** containing a given branch from command line?

I have checked out `feature-whatever` branch. It is part of PR #83 (which I can verify via github webbrowser), but I would like to determine this

- from the cloned git repo
- via command line

```
$ git status
On branch feature-whatever
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature-whatever'.
...

$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  origin/PR-82
  origin/PR-83
  origin/develop
  origin/feature/feature-whatever
  origin/feature/feature-something-else
  origin/main
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be more than one GitHub pull request that contains any given commit.

Given your own `git branch -r` output, you want a simple `--contains`:

```
git branch -r --contains feature-whatever
```

This should list `origin/PR-83` in your case.  Note that I assume you created `origin/PR-83` from GitHub's `refs/pull/83/head` name, perhaps with `git fetch origin +refs/pull/83/head:refs/heads/PR-83`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Maybe I mislead you with "is part of PR #83". 
My branch `feature-whatever` is tracking the remote branch `origin/feature/feature-whatever`. Actually for `$git branch -r --contains feature-whatever` I only get `origin/feature-whatever` and not the desired `PR-83`. Same picture, if I also checkout `PR-83` to track `origin/PR-83`.

Comment: Wait, so `PR-83` is actually someone's branch name (`refs/heads/PR-83`) in a GitHub repository? The actual pull request ref names on GitHub are in the `refs/pull/` name-space that is specific to GitHub. That's why I said *Note that I assume ...* in the last paragraph of the answer.